# 20kg digital servo not working, probably because my frequency calculations are very wrong (raspberry pi)

Tags: motor, raspberry-pi, servo, python, duty-cycle

## summary

I changed my servos for a more powerful one and cannot get it to work, I believe it is because I can't get the right duty cycle calculation in the code

## explanation

I have a robotic arm that I started programming for fun, got everything working but the servos that came with the arm where way too weak, someone recommended [this one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B01N0XGBCJ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&th=1) which sure look more robust, today it arrived so I thought it would be just about replace it, for my surprise it doesn't work at all.

after investigating I think it'S because I didn't set the right duty cycle, I never heard about it before but I tried to calculate it with information I found on internet, but after hours I still couldn't get it to work properly.

sometimes it moves but definitely not to the right angle and it is not consistent, but because I'm new in all of this I don't even know if that is the reason.

I'm unsure if I only need to update the `SERVO_MIN_DUTY` or if I must change the hertz when I set up the GPIO PWM, too.

## Servos

This is the [**old servo**](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Diymore-Digital-Helicopter-Airplane-controls/dp/B07DQJ1JXY/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=MG996&qid=1586120267&s=industrial&sr=1-1):

- **Operating Speed** : 0.17sec / 60 degrees (4.8V no load)
- Operating Speed : 0.13sec / 60 degrees (6.0V no load).
- **Stall Torque** : 13 kg-cm (180.5 oz-in) at 4.8V;
- Stall Torque : 15 kg-cm (208.3 oz-in) at 6V.

this is the [**new servo**](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B01N0XGBCJ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&th=1):

- **Item**: DS3218 20KG Large Torque Digital Servo
- Stall Torque (5V): 19 kg/cm (263.8oz/in)
- Stall Torque (6.8V): 21.5  kg/cm (298.5 oz/in)
- Speed : 0.16 sec/60°(5V) / 0.14 sec/60°(6.8V)
- Operating Voltage: 4.8 ~ 6.8 DC Volts
- Dead brand: 3μs
- Weight: 60 g
- Motor Type: DC Motor Gear
- Type: Copper & Aluminum
- **Working frequence**: 1520μs / 333Hz
- Size: 40 x 20 x 40.5 mm
- Features:

  - High performance digital standard servo
  - High-precision metal gears with hard anodizing
  - CNC aluminium middle Shell
  - Dual ball bearings

The original code (I tried to update it using the data I found around without success,mostly from [this guide](http://www.robotplatform.com/knowledge/servo/servo_control_tutorial.html))

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
OFFSE_DUTY = 0.5        #define pulse offset of servo
SERVO_MIN_DUTY = 2.5+OFFSE_DUTY     #define pulse duty cycle for minimum angle of servo
SERVO_MAX_DUTY = 12.5+OFFSE_DUTY    #define pulse duty cycle for maximum angle of servo
servoPin = 12

def map( value, fromLow, fromHigh, toLow, toHigh):  # map a value from one range to another range
    return (toHigh-toLow)*(value-fromLow) / (fromHigh-fromLow) + toLow

def setup():
    global p
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)         # use PHYSICAL GPIO Numbering
    GPIO.setup(servoPin, GPIO.OUT)   # Set servoPin to OUTPUT mode
    GPIO.output(servoPin, GPIO.LOW)  # Make servoPin output LOW level

    p = GPIO.PWM(servoPin, 50)     # set Frequece to 50Hz
    p.start(0)                     # Set initial Duty Cycle to 0
    
def servoWrite(angle):      # make the servo rotate to specific angle, 0-180 
    if(angle<0):
        angle = 0
    elif(angle > 180):
        angle = 180
    p.ChangeDutyCycle(map(angle,0,180,SERVO_MIN_DUTY,SERVO_MAX_DUTY)) # map the angle to duty cycle and output it
    
def loop():
    while True:
        for dc in range(0, 181, 1):   # make servo rotate from 0 to 180 deg
            servoWrite(dc)     # Write dc value to servo
            time.sleep(0.001)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        for dc in range(180, -1, -1): # make servo rotate from 180 to 0 deg
            servoWrite(dc)
            time.sleep(0.001)
        time.sleep(0.5)

def destroy():
    p.stop()
    GPIO.cleanup()

if __name__ == '__main__':     # Program entrance
    print ('Program is starting...')
    setup()
    try:
        loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:  # Press ctrl-c to end the program.
        destroy()
```

So what exactly do I need from there to know exactly how to update the code for any servo?

The item description says 0.16 for 60° so I expected to be able to get it with a rule of 3 (for 180° I could do a 0.16 x 180 / 60 = 0.48s, but that result seems to high for my little understanding).

Comment: you have to use a power supply, otherwise the servo will not move

Comment: Possible help here https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/58232/cant-drive-servo

Comment: How is the power supply holding up under the bigger load of these new servos?

Comment: this is correct! After updating the servo I also put the voltage up to the recommended by the servo description, but it looks like it is not enough, if I put it up to 9v (more than it is supposed to be, but I assume my power supply also give less amp) the servo comes back to live, I assumed it was the code because I had the recommended voltage and changes in the code would make the servo move sometimes (still do not understand why) How do I manage this situation in terms of accepted answer in a comment?

Comment: If you increased the PSU to 9V you may have damaged the servos. You probably need a PSU with higher rated *current*, not voltage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5 volt at 3 amps and the servo works 100%, the problem is that even with the correct voltage I didn't have enough amp to push the servo.

I also found  [this guide](https://medium.com/@rovai/pan-tilt-multi-servo-control-62f723d03f26) that helped a lot in terms of calculating and understanding the limits of my servos as it explains every single step and the whole maths behind it in a very simple way (I read quite a few and was always confuse about the whole thing)

Comment: You should not need to power your servo from 9V, and you should **not** do it.  Get a power supply that can deliver the needed current at the specified voltage.  I have a couple of DS3218 servos just like yours.  They run just fine on the specified voltage.

Comment: Hi JRE, thanks for answering once more, I can see in the servo description that a recommended voltage is between 4.8 ~ 6.8, with 9 it is 100% working as I expected, played with it for hours yesterday, but I understand it is not ideal, I assume that the problem is that my power supply do not give enough amp at 6 volts but I cannot see any amp indication in the servo description, only volts, is there something I should be looking for to know it before hand? (I'm still learning and would like to know those things)

Comment: I put it in a 5v with 3 amp and it works perfectly fine too,edited the answer, thank you for the advice JRE (still unsure if that is too much amp though!)

Comment: The servo will only take the current it needs.  Your power supply can deliver up to 3A, but won't force the servo to take all 3A.

Comment: I see, I didn't know that, when I was studying about this I basically put in my head that every device received W , which is basically V x A, so I assumed there were no difference in which one is bigger as long as the W is about right, I will investigate, thank you again for your time

Answer (score 1):

You should not have needed to change any code if both servos have the same angle limits.

The digital servo does not need a pulse 333 times per second.

0.16sec/60° is the shaft speed, not the HI pulse required. The pulse should still be 1500us for center, 1000us for one extreme and 2000us for the other extreme.

Comment: @ChrisStratton What makes his inputs oddball? They look standard as far as I can tell. The servos are fairly standard too.